# Loki query to show all logs

Tags: grafana-loki

I'm trying to test our Loki log data source.  From the Queries I've been executing nothing is returned.

It's possible that the logs are in a different format to what I'm expecting, or that no Logs are ingested by Loki, and my pipeline is broken somewhere.

Is there a Loki query that returns all the logs?

I've looked through documentation, and so far, I haven't found any such Loki query.  Any other queries to help debug would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a match-all regex together with a stream you have for all your logs.

For example if you collect a stream named `host` for all your incoming logs you'd query for:

```
{host=~ ".*"}
```

You should note that at present a [stream selector is always required](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/) for querying logs.

Comment: Grafana v9.3.6 parser complains: `parse error : queries require at least one regexp or equality matcher that does not have an empty-compatible value. For instance, app=~".*" does not meet this requirement, but app=~".+" will`

Answer (score 14):

`{host=~ ".*"}` doesn't work for me. Use `{host=~ ".+"}` That should work always.

Comment: Note that Loki limits the number of returned log lines per query to 5000 - see [these docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/v2.8.x/tools/logcli/#batched-queries). It may prevent from returning all the results for queries matching more than 5k log lines. If you need returning all the matching log lines in streaming manner, then take a look [at this system](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/VictoriaLogs/querying/#command-line).

Answer (score -1):

recommend use the `label=~".+"`, this is the efficat way.

Of cause, use the `label!="", label=~".*"`, is all right, but it's possible return `504 Timeout`

Comment: By default, records in loki don't have label named `label`, thus your queries will return nothing. What did you mean by your answer?